# How to change class CSS using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to edit my classes CSS (`div.result`) using the following...

```
$('.result').css('top', '55%');
```

however, it doesn't appear to be updating.. any ideas why? What am I doing wrong?

Below is the relevant CSS. The Javascript I'm using and the javascript which renders the div resides in `cr.js`.

**HTML**

```
 <div id='cr' style='width:510px; height:440px; display:none; overflow:auto'>
    <script src = "js/c.js"></script>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.result {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
}
```

Comment: What's the position value for your CSS? `top` won't work with `static`

Comment: is `.result` `position: relative` or `absolute`?

Comment: wait, do you want to update the elements of the class `.result` or the class itself? I don't think the second is possible, but also not necessary since the first has the same effect

Comment: can you post your HTML? The snippet you posted is correct

Comment: See update. I'd like to update the elements of the class. before top was 20% now I want the elements to be 55%.

Comment: You don't seem to be applying the `result` class to the actual DIV?

Comment: Also, not sure if this is a typo but the script you are referencing is not cr.js as you stated, but rather c.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      1>  $('#cr').removeClass('.result');
      2>    $('#cr').addClass('.result_top');
css
```

`div.result_top`
`{`

`div.result_top
{`
`over here you can put your new css.`
`}`

if u just want to append the css
such as

`div.result top{
}`

than just remove line 1 it would do the work

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery ".removeClass" / ".addClass" methods.

take a look to this articles:

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/